# WP_Query causing links to not work

Tags: wp-query, loop, sticky-post

adding this line of code and adjusting my if statement has damaged my links in the loop. I really don't understand why this has happened. What is wrong with the line of code?

```
        <?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) ); ?>

          <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

            <div class="posts__post">

                <article>
                    <a class="posts__post--preview" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <p class="posts__post--tag"><?php the_category('&nbsp;/&nbsp;'); ?></p>
                    <h1 class="posts__post--title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                    <p class="posts__post--meta"><?php echo time_ago(); ?></p>
                </article>   


            </div>

          <?php endwhile; else :?>

          <h1><?php _e('no post where found!','blog'); ?></h1>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div>
```

Comment: Can you try wp_reset_postdata(); after your custom query code to see if it helps?

Comment: I added after `endwhile` and still no luck.

Comment: How are the links damaged? Which links are damaged? In the loop or outside the loop?

Comment: In the loop. `the_permalink()`

Comment: Yes, describe damage please. Or give us a live view at it. Is it broken? How it's displayed in the final source HTML of page?

Comment: might be a problem of your formatting and CSS ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. I didn't create a `single.php` file. In my learnings I have discovered that if no single.php file exist then Wordpress falls back to `index.php`. So the link were actually working but just using the same template. Again im sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: There is a plugin called "Theme Check" that is going to tell you exactly what your theme is missing. Might be worth installing.